# Joomla Blog Universal Read More

Tags: joomla, menu, blogs, joomla-article

So I have this Joomla website going and I'm creating a blog page. All featured articles go into Menu "Blog" no problem. The problem comes when I need to add a "Read More". I know I can do this with the "Read More" button that each article has but I want to make it a universal read more. Either after so many characters or so many words add the "Read More". Is this possible through Joomla's admin panel? If not can I add some PHP in one of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of extensions on the Joomla! Extensions directory that do this type of auto "Read More" so there isn't a need to hack together something.

Have a look at the sub-section on [Article Summary](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/article-elements/articles-summary) extensions.  Also there are components like the [foobla Full RSS](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-edition/automatic-articles/11403) that produce automatic summary (ie. read-mores) from the article feeds they pull in.

Comment: I was going to recommend using a template override to do this, but the way that Joomla 1.5 decides to display a read more or not is not conducive to what you want to do. You would have to insert the read more line anyhow to make it work, unless you hack the core. You are better off just getting a module that does it built in.

Comment: Something already existing is really the best bet.  You could write your own that looks at the number of words and inserts readmore there, but why?  No need to reinvent the wheel!  I'm with cppl & Brent on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Look below the textbox on the article page (where you edit the content of the article). You should see a "read more" button there.

If you don't like the behavior of the "read more" button, you can implement it yourself easily by creating a like with the anchor text "read more" - the link will be to another article which contains the "part II" of the article you're editing.

More about articles you can find [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Article_Management)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla autoreadmore plugin
http://gruz.org.ua/en/extensions/autoreadmore-plugin-for-joomla.html

- Automatically adds "Read more..." link after a configurable number of characters, words or paragraphs.
- Will not break HTML or break the article in the middle of a word.
- Preserves formatting (optionally) and fixes unclosed tags if php-tidy or php DOMDocument is installed at the server (most modern servers have it installed)
- Works with joomla articles and third party extensions (like k2).
- Works for modules.
- Configurable to ignore or to work for specific categories, articles
- Allows to place the first image found in the article to the introtext beginning, so you have your blog illustrated.
- Optionally ignores manually inserted readmore break
- And some other options.